About a recent question of mine closed within minutes:
I asked a pretty big question on overflow sometime ago :
Some (philosophical) investigations on possible future of proof of Riemann Hypothesis with possible approach :
Clearly I have written "possible future of proof " not "possible proof".
It was closed within minutes stating same reason that its asking to check a proof or announcing a result but both are not the case.
Also surprisingly the question requires couple of minutes to read let alone understand. Also there are clear questions at the end of the post .
I'm really shocked by this response!?
What's wrong with the question !?

If you have to ask why proposing a potential solution to RH (no matter how far off in the future) is off-topic, then my guess is that you haven't had to wade through years of people clamouring to push their flawed claimed proofs on you. Even "possible future of proof" is close enough to "possible proof" to be in off-topic territory. Please don't rules-lawyer the distinction here.
Because, what do you expect an answer to be? "Yes, this should work"? If you want to think about the technique itself, just ask about that, and forget an application to RH. Or, better, isolate a weaker result (ideally a known theorem) where you think the technique will work, and say something new and interesting, and then use that as the context. Working on achievable goals is what MO is meant to help with, not finding out if your idea to attack the biggest open problem in mathematics might possibly, maybe, in the future, yield results.
